# How to Make Children "giggle" in a Hide and Seek Game with 2D Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I don't know how to add a "giggle" effect to my Hide and Seek game. If the player guesses within one "spot" of a hidden child in any direct (up/down, left/right/diagonally), the hidden child should "giggle" to give a hint to the player The output can be System.out.println("*giggle*");. I am struggling with the logic and coding behind it. The reason I want to do this, is to show the person playing the game, that they are close. If you guess (0,0), it shows that the child is close. It can either be in (1,0), (1,1), or (0,1). [Supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTuHx.png)

```
    public static int columns = 10;
public static int rows = 10;
public static String[][] map = new String[columns][rows];
public static int [][] missedGuesses = new int[columns][rows]; 
public static int children = 3;
public static final int maxAttempts = 3; 
public static int attempts = 0; 
public static int playerAttempts;
public static int childrenFound = 0; 


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Welcome text
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hide and Seek!");
    System.out.println("You have to guess where all the children are. You have 10 atttempts and 3 children to find.");
    System.out.println("");

    // The phases of the game
    createMap();
    
    hidingChildren();
    
    do {
    guessPhase();
    } while (childrenFound != children && ++ attempts < maxAttempts );
    gameOver();
}

public static void createMap() {
    // Creates the 10x10 Grid 
       System.out.print("  ");
       for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
               System.out.print(i);
       System.out.println();
       for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
               map[i][j] = " ";
               if (j == 0)
                   System.out.print(i + "|" + map[i][j]);
               else if (j == map[i].length - 1)
                   System.out.print(map[i][j] + "|" + i);
               else
                   System.out.print(map[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.print("  ");
       for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
           System.out.print(i);
       System.out.println();
       } 


 public static void updateMap() {
    //Updates the 10x10 Grid
     System.out.println();
        System.out.print("  ");
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
        for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(x + "|");

            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++){
                System.out.print(map[x][y]);
            }

            System.out.println("|" + x);
        }
        System.out.print("  ");
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
        
    }

 public static void hidingChildren() {
     //Hides the children
      System.out.println("Hiding the Children!");
      for (int i = 1; i <= children;) {
      int x = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      int y = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      if((x >= 0 && x < rows) && (y >= 0 && y < columns) && (map[x][y] == " "))
           {
              System.out.println(i + " - Finished Hiding Children!");
            //To see the children insert map[x][y] = "x"; into the line below before the }
                  map[x][y] = "x";
              }
              i++;
              } 
      
      }
  
  public static void playerMove() {
      //Player inserts x and y coordinates
      int x = -1;
      int y = -1;
      do {
   
            Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.print("Choose a X coordinate: ");
            x = playerInput.nextInt();
            
            System.out.print("Choose a Y coordinate: ");
            y = playerInput.nextInt();
            
            // Player guesses
            if ((x >= 0 && x < rows) && (y >= 0 && y < columns));
            {
                if (map[y][x] == "x") 
                {
                    System.out.println("You found a child!");
                    map[y][x] = "!"; 
                    ++childrenFound;
                    attempts = -1;
                } else if (map[x][y] == " ") {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you looked in the wrong place!");
                    map[y][x] = "-";
            
                }  else if ((x < 0 || x >= rows) || (y < 0 || y >= columns))  
                    System.out.println("You can't find children outside the " + rows + " by " + columns + " grid");
             }  
              } while((x < 0 || x >= rows) || (y < 0 || y >= columns));  
      
  }
  
  public static void amountGuesses () {
      //To keep track of guesses 
    
    Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        playerAttempts = playerInput.nextInt();
    
  }
      
  public static void guessPhase() {
      // Guessing phase of the game
      int result = maxAttempts - attempts; 
      System.out.println("Guesses left: " + result);
      System.out.println("Children found: " + childrenFound);
          playerMove();
          amountGuesses();
          updateMap();
  }
  public static void gameOver() {
    //If one of these condition are reached, the game ends
      if (childrenFound == 3) {
          System.out.println("Winner!");
         
          
      } else if (attempts == maxAttempts)
            System.out.println("You lose. The amount of children left are: " + children);          
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed some bugs and added giggle feature. `isNear(int x, int y)` tells whether to giggle or not. Giggles will be shown as `?` in the grid.
Update the code as per your needs.

Output:

```
Guesses left: 1
Children found: 1
Choose a X coordinate: 5
Choose a Y coordinate: 1
Giggle!!
  0123456789
0|    ?     |0
1|     ?    |1
2|          |2
3|         !|3
4|          |4
5|          |5
6|          |6
7|          |7
8|          |8
9|          |9
  0123456789
```

Code:

```
public class Test {
    public static int columns = 10;
    public static int rows = 10;
    public static String[][] map = new String[columns][rows];
    public static int children = 3;
    public static final int maxAttempts = 3;
    public static int attempts = 0;
    public static int playerAttempts;
    public static int childrenFound = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Welcome text
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hide and Seek!");
        System.out
                .println("You have to guess where all the children are. You have 10 atttempts and 3 children to find.");
        System.out.println("");

        // The phases of the game
        initializeMap();
        printMap(false);

        hidingChildren();
        printMap(true); // comment this statement in production

        do {
            guessPhase();
        } while (childrenFound != children && ++attempts < maxAttempts);
        gameOver();
    }

    public static void initializeMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                map[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printMap(boolean showChildren) {
        String data = "";
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                if (showChildren)
                    data = map[i][j];
                else
                    data = map[i][j].equals("x") ? " " : map[i][j];

                if (j == 0)
                    System.out.print(i + "|" + data);
                else if (j == map[i].length - 1)
                    System.out.print(data + "|" + i);
                else
                    System.out.print(data);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void hidingChildren() {
        // Hides the children
        System.out.println("Hiding the Children!");
        for (int i = 1; i <= children;) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            if ((x >= 0 && x < rows) && (y >= 0 && y < columns) && (map[x][y] == " ")) {
                System.out.println(i + " - Finished Hiding Children!");
                map[x][y] = "x";
                i++;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void playerMove() {
        // Player inserts x and y coordinates
        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;
        Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Choose a X coordinate: ");
            x = playerInput.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Choose a Y coordinate: ");
            y = playerInput.nextInt();

            // Player guesses
            if ((x >= 0 && x < rows) && (y >= 0 && y < columns))
                
            {
                if (map[y][x] == "x") {
                    System.out.println("You found a child!");
                    map[y][x] = "!";
                    ++childrenFound;
                } else if (map[y][x].equals(" ")) {
                    if (isNear(y, x)) {
                        System.out.println("Giggle!!");
                        map[y][x] = "?";
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you looked in the wrong place!");
                        map[y][x] = "-";
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter new coordinates.");
                }
                    
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't find children outside the " + rows + " by " + columns + " grid");
            }
        } while ((x < 0 || x > rows) || (y < 0 || y > columns));
    }

    public static void amountGuesses() {
        // To keep track of guesses

        // Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        // playerAttempts = playerInput.nextInt();
        playerAttempts++;
    }

    public static void guessPhase() {
        // Guessing phase of the game
        int result = maxAttempts - attempts;
        System.out.println("Guesses left: " + result);
        System.out.println("Children found: " + childrenFound);
        playerMove();
        amountGuesses();
        printMap(false);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------\n");
    }

    public static boolean isNear(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                if (map[i][j].equals("x")) {
                    int xl = Math.abs(i - x);
                    int yl = Math.abs(j - y);
                    if ((xl == 1 && yl == 1) || 
                            (xl == 0 && yl == 1) || 
                            (xl == 1 && yl == 0)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void gameOver() {
        // If one of these condition are reached, the game ends
        if (childrenFound == 3) {
            System.out.println("Winner!");

        } else if (attempts == maxAttempts)
            System.out.println("You lose. The amount of children left are: " + (children - childrenFound));
    }

}
```